# Should I leave a beer age before drinking it?

Tags: aging

I think the title is self explanatory, but I would like to add: does it make any difference letting it aging in a can or in a bottle?

Comment: What kind of beer?

Comment: I don't know... Maybe I should have asked what kind of beers should age before being drunk?

Comment: [How can I tell whether a beer will improve with age?](http://beer.stackexchange.com/q/99)

Comment: This would be better asked as focusing on aging in cans vs. bottles.  It's not a duplicate as such, but it's very poorly differentiated.